# find all webservers running HTTP and not HTTPS

Tags: bash, nmap

I'm trying to build a list of all servers that are running HTTP and not redirecting to HTTPS. Using the following nmap command to build the list:

```
nmap -Pn -p80,8080 --open -oG webserver.txt 10.0.0.0/8
```

Can anyone think of a tool I could use to leverage in bash script to check if there is no HTTPS redirect? i'm drawing a blank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take following codes as a base. I assume that you have parsed output of ip address list at inside of iplist.txt

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in $(cat iplist.txt)
do
        CODE=$(timeout 10 curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" $ip)
        echo ""
        if [[ "$CODE" = "301" ]] || [[ "$CODE" = "302" ]]; then
                echo "Status code is $CODE Redirection DETECTED!"
        else
                echo "Status code is $CODE No redirection.."
        fi
done
```

Comment: Bingo! thanks a ton!! those curl flags were exactly what i was looking for. Many thanks for going out of your way and just writing the whole script!